# How to exchange data between HTML and a Code Snippet? (Wordpress)

Tags: php, html, wordpress, code-snippets

I'm using the Code Snippets plugin for Wordpress to keep some code running that handles file names whenever files are uploaded in my website. The code is written in PHP. I understand how POST works to exchange data between HTML and PHP, but I'm not sure how to do so when my code is inside a Code Snippet instead of a regular .php file.

What I actually have to do is pretty simple: I have a radio button and I need to use that information for an "if" instruction.

Has anyone ever done anything similar?

Comment: You should add some of your codes here so people can visualize it more.